# Code is getting a 106 error in Pascal, and I am not sure why

Tags: pascal

I'm still fairly new to Pascal and I'm getting these errors and I'm not sure why. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Runtime error 106 at $004015DFF
                     $004015DF
                     $004016D2
                     $004016FD
                     $004078D1
```

This is my code if you guys want to take a look.

```
program BasicReadWrite;

type
  ArrayOfPersons = record
    name: String;
    age: String; 
  end;

procedure WriteLinesToFile(var myFile: TextFile);
begin
  WriteLn(myFile, 5);
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Fred Smith');
  WriteLn(myFile, 28);
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Jill Jones');
  WriteLn(myFile, 54);
  WriteLn(myFile, 'John Doe');
  WriteLn(myFile, 15);
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Samantha Pritchard');
  WriteLn(myFile, 19);
  WriteLn(myFile, 'Hans Fredrickson');
  WriteLn(myFile, 77);
end;

procedure PrintRecordsToTerminal(personArray: ArrayOfPersons; count: 
  Integer);
begin
  WriteLn('Person name: ', personArray.name);
  WriteLn('Age: ', personArray.age);
end;

procedure ReadLinesFromFile(var myFile: TextFile);
var 
  p: ArrayOfPersons;
  number: Integer;
begin
  number := 0;
  while number <= 19 do
  begin
    ReadLn(myFile, number);
    ReadLn(myFile, p.name[number]);
    ReadLn(myFile, p.age);
    number := number + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You have written the number of records that the file contains to the file; that's "5". You're trying to read 20 records. You should read "number" **before** the while loop, and loop from 0 to number - 1.

Comment: oh, but isnt the number age? and i want to be able to record up to 20 arrays, so how do i do that?

Comment: There is a problem with your declaration of `ArrayOfPersons` . The name implies an array, but declaration says a single record. And the `number` index is used to read a single character of the name instead of an array element of a record. Fix the declaration and index the record properly.

Comment: `program BasicReadWrite;

type
  ArrayOfPersons = record
        name: array of String;
        age: array of String;
  end;`
so like this? 
I'm not really sure how you index the record properly.

Comment: No, `type ArrayOfPersons = array of TPerson;` where `TPerson = record name: String; age : Integer; end;`. Depending on the pascal compiler, you may need to have a static array declaration:`ArrayOfPersons = array[1..xx] of TPerson;` As for indexing the array: `personArray[number].name` is one example.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the direct question:

> I'm getting these errors and I'm not sure why.

The reason is you are reading a non-numeric value when a numeric value is expected.

The text file is written with the number of records at the first line. Then follows the record information, one after the other.

You are always reading the record count number plus the record information, and end up with reading a number when a record data is expected.

---

There is a problem with your declaration of `ArrayOfPersons`. The name implies an array, but declaration says a single record. And the number index is used to read a single character of the name, instead of an array element of a record. Fix the declaration and index the record properly.

```
const cMaxPersons = 20;
type
  TPerson = record 
    name: String; 
    age : Integer; 
  end;
  ArrayOfPersons = array[0..cMaxPersons-1] of TPerson;

procedure ReadLinesFromFile(var myFile: TextFile);
var 
  p: ArrayOfPersons;
  i,number: Integer;
begin
  ReadLn(myFile, number);
  if number <= cMaxPersons then
  begin
    for i := 0 to number-1 do 
    begin
      ReadLn(myFile, p[number].name);
      ReadLn(myFile, p[number].age);
    end;
  end;
end;
```